# Pipe to another command bash

Tags: bash, tar, gunzip

I cannot seem to get my bash script to work, i want to pipe the output from the gunzip command to another command but it is not working, can anyone help me?

The gunzip command outputs a tar file that i want to then use the tar command to put back yo the original file.

```
# let the user choose what they want to Restore
echo -n "Select the file or directory you want to Restore" 
read Chosendata 

echo -e "Starting Restore"

# unziping files
gunzip ${Chosendata} | tar xvf -                        #Here
# end the restore.
echo -e "Restore complete"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `gunzip -c`.

```
  -c, --stdout      write on standard output, keep original files unchanged
```

Or **tar** only: `tar -xzf ${Chosendata}`.